# How to design content URIs for notifyChange using many-to-many sqlite relationship?

Tags: android, sqlite

Im building an Android app that has sqlite tables for `Content` and `Tag`. Every `Content` can have one or more `Tag`s and a tag can be attached to one or more `Content`s. To create the many-to-many relationship I have a sqlite table called `Content_Tag` created something like:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTENT_TAG (
  CONTENT_ID STRING NOT NULL,
  TAG_ID STRING NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CONTENT_ID, TAG_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CONTENT_ID) REFERENCES CONTENT (_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (TAG_ID) REFERENCES TAG (_ID)
);
```

Then, to provide the ability to fetch all the `Tag`s for a `Content` (or conversely, the content for a tag) I create a View:

```
CREATE VIEW CONTENT_TAG_VIEW AS
SELECT ...
FROM CONTENT_TAG
JOIN CONTENT ON CONTENT_TAG.CONTENT_ID = CONTENT._ID
JOIN TAG ON CONTENT_TAG.TAG_ID = TAG._ID;
```

Now what I would like to do is design my Content URIs in such a way that if an UPDATE is performed on an item in the `Tag` table then when I call `notifyChange(uri)` all the `Content` with that tag will be updated with the new `Tag` information.

I understand that Content URIs will also notify descendants of the URI so it seems that I could just notify on the base URI for all content (and have every piece of content update). But that may be inefficient if only a few pieces of Content have changed.

Is there a better way to perform the notification?

Comment: Are you using ContentProvider?

Comment: " But that may be inefficient " so that sentence is not verified?

Comment: @Sirlate yes, I have a class that extends from ContentProvider

Comment: @pkskink correct - not verified. Intuitively it seems inefficient to have every piece of content receive an update. But perhaps android has some magic under the hood that takes care of this? Or perhaps theres another way Im not aware of to ensure the notifyChange happens efficiently? Im new to Android dev so the answer isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I did in similar situation and worked perfectly:

I had a table name Messages and MessagesProvider. I had a view like yours and its content provider called HistoryProvider. In MessageProvider at the end of each of these method `delete`, `insert`, and `update` there should be a line that you are notifying content observers on this content provider, some thing like this:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

so I added another line to notify content observers on HistoryProvider too:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(HistoryProvider.CONTENT_URI , null);
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

and at the end of your `query` method in MessageProvider, I did this:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), HistoryProvider.CONTENT_URI);
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

and that's it! So if your content providers was written right, it should work like a charm.

Comment: Interesting idea having multiple setNotificationUris. Ill give that a shot. Thanks!